# Updating an array of Data in Vue JS

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.3, vue-resource

i'm trying to make a little DataTable in VueJS 2.0, and i've hit a bit of a roadblock, i'm making a call to a backend route to get some JSON from records in the Database, so far so good.

I want those records to populate an Array of GridData that i will later iterate through and display on my table.
The problem here is that it's not working...

```
Vue.http.post('/getData', data).then((response) => {
    this.gridData = response.body;
});
```

I have my data setup as follows

```
    data: () => {
        return {
            searchQuery: "",
            columns: ['ID', 'Name', 'Campaign', 'Method', 'Limit Per Connection', 'Limit Per Day', 'Active', 'Successes', 'Failures', 'Last Ran'],
            lastId: 0,
            rowsPerPage: 10,
            gridData: []
        }
    }
```

And my function that gets the data is called on the *mounted* hook

```
    mounted() {
        this.fetchData(this.lastId, this.rowsPerPage);
    },
```

Am i doing anything wrong here?

Comment: How your fetchData method looks like ? And if you want to populate your data, and store them in array, why your are using POST request ? You should go with GET.

Answer (score 0):

You are using POST HTTP Request, instead of GET.POST is for creating new records in API/DB.

I think this should work for you

```
data() {
        return {
            searchQuery: "",
            columns: ['ID', 'Name', 'Campaign', 'Method', 'Limit Per Connection', 'Limit Per Day', 'Active', 'Successes', 'Failures', 'Last Ran'],
            lastId: 0,
            rowsPerPage: 10,
            gridData: []
        }
},

created() {
  this.fetchData()
},

methods: {
  fetchData() {
   this.$http.get('/getData')
     .then(result => {
       this.gridData = result.data
       // or this.gridData = result.json()
     })
  }
}
```